# How does the author get ${P(T_{\text{new}}\leq 6|y_N) = \int P(Y_{new}\leq 6|r)p(r|y_N)dr}$

Tags: bayesian

So this is probably a really stupid question, but I don't get where this particular formula comes from. I'm reading a Machine Learning book, and at one point the author states the following formula:

$$
P(Y_{new}\leq 6|y_N) = \int P(Y_{new}\leq 6|r)p(r|y_N)dr
$$
my first thought is that this comes from
$$
P(Y) = \int p(Y,r)dr = \int p(Y|r)p(r)dr
$$
but it doesn't really "match" the above form. If you let ${Y=Y_{new}\leq 6|y_N}$ you end up with
$$
P(Y_{new}\leq 6|y_N) = \int p(Y_{new}\leq 6|y_N,r)p(r)dr
$$
am I missing something stupid and obvious? If more context is needed I can provide it. I usually do lots of pure Mathematics so I'm finding statistics and applying it in this context a bit tricky. Thank you!

**Edit**: to provide a bit more context, I'll setup the problem covered in the book. It's going over prior and posterior distributions, with the parameter we are interested in being $r$ (which is the probability of getting a heads with a coin toss). ${y_N}$ is the number of heads observed in $N$ throws and ${Y_{new}}$ is meant to be the number of heads observed in a batch of ${10}$ throws. Essentially the game is: if you get ${6}$ heads or less in ${10}$ throws, you win. Of course the game should be in your favour if we assume the coin is fair, but the idea I guess is to challenge this *prior* belief given evidence. He writes
$$
p(r|y_N) = \frac{p(y_N|r)p(r)}{\int p(y_N|r)p(r)dr}
$$
(which I know comes from Bayes formula). ${p(r)}$ is the prior and ${p(y_N|r)}$ is the likelihood, and lastly ${p(r|y_N)}$ is the posterior. He said given this, we can find the chance of getting ${6}$ heads in a new batch of throws by finding
$$
P(Y_{new}\leq 6|y_N) = E[P(Y_{new}\leq 6|r)] = \int P(Y_{new}\leq 6|r)p(r|y_N)dr
$$
It's this part I'm unsure where it comes from.

Comment: Can you provide a full citation?

Comment: @chl of course I can yes! I'll edit the question now

Comment: @chl edited now, the book I am following is "FCML : First Course in Machine Learning", and this part is in Chapter 3 (it's one of the first few pages of Chapter 3). I've tried to summarize though in the question now the full context to help with background information - let me know if you need anymore. Thanks once again :)

Comment: maybe $Y_{new}$ depends on $r$ and it depends on $y_n$ but at the beginning it was shortly stated as $P(Y_{new}|y_n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general fact of conditional probabilities
$$
\Pr(A,B) = \Pr(A\mid B)\cdot \Pr(B)
$$
also holds for conditional expectations
$$
\Pr(A,B\mid C) = \Pr(A \mid B,C) \cdot \Pr(B\mid C)
$$
Instead of A, B, and C, we have here $Y_{new}$, $r$, and $y_N$.  We can say
$$ \Pr(Y_{new},r \mid y_N) = \Pr(Y_{new} \mid r,y_N) \cdot \Pr(r\mid y_N) $$
Given the setup of the problem, $Y_{new}$ is independent of $y_N$ when given $r$.  That is,
$$ \Pr(Y_{new} \mid r,y_N) = \Pr(Y_{new} \mid r) $$

Those last two statements allow

$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y_{new} \mid y_N) &= \int \Pr(Y_{new},r \mid y_N) dr \\
&= \int \Pr(Y_{new} \mid r,y_N) \cdot \Pr(r \mid y_N) dr \\
&= \int \Pr(Y_{new} \mid r) \cdot  \Pr(r \mid y_N) dr
\end{align}
$$

which is the desired result.

Comment: Ahhhh I see! Since ${r}$ depends on ${y_N}$ and ${Y_{new}}$ depends on ${r}$, it doesn't matter if you are given both ${r}$ and ${y_N}$ when considering ${Y_{new}}$ - you only need ${r}$. In other words the dependence is "captured" in ${r}$. I appreciate it! Thank you!